# Sum of a Geometric series Approximately 2? or exactly 2? (1+1/2+1/4+...)

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question is not only asking specifically about the answer, but how to get there. I've always had the notion that this infinite series when summed up would be very close to 2, but not exactly 2. I'm not sure if this is simple to answer or hard. I'm curious about the properties of infinity, but may not have the knowledge to delve into it. I've studied up to Calculus 2 in College if that helps.

Comment: The summation of 1/n is divergent. That is, it will tend to infinity as you add more numbers.

Comment: I believe you are thinking about the series $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$.

Comment: yeah I fumbled on the number sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the sum in question is actually the geometric

$$1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\dots=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{-i}$$

If we compute a partial sum at

$$S(n)=\sum_{i =0}^{n}2^{-i}$$

we find that we can evaluate $2-S(n)=2^{-n}$.  So each time we increase $n$ by one, we close the distance from the amount we have summed up to the limit amount of $2$ by cutting that distance in half.  Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, we see that $2-S(n)=2^{-n}\to 0$, and therefore $S(n)\to 2$.  The sum only reaches $2$ in the limit; at every partial sum along the way, there is still a non-zero distance between the sum and $2$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should create another post for this question, but is there a reason why ∞+1 = ∞? as well as ∞*5=∞? I get that ∞+1 would just mean that the starting number would be 2 instead of 1 and it would go up to infinity, the same for ∞*5 where you go up by the multiple of 5s. But it feels like it should be bigger. Like 5∞ > ∞.

Comment: @Terry0: so take such a limit, for example $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n+1\over n}\cdot{5n^2-65n+2\over 22+n^2}$$ You are welcome to ask further questions to get more information.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. In this equation 5 indeed makes a difference, but is this only true for limits to go towards infinities?

I ask this because of this term Aelph Null, in which a video has explained Aelph Null + 1 does not mean it is greater than Aelph Null (or 0), because it's suppose to hold all cardinal numbers

Comment: We only have definable concepts of infinity in terms of limits.  Even an integral taken with infinity as one (or both) of the bounds is evaluated using a limit, but we can often take a shortcut and just "plug in infinity" once the integral has been evaluated.  But behind pretty much every mention of infinity is either a limit or an induction argument.

Comment: Also, $\aleph_0$ is the "smallest" cardinal infinity, aligning with the natural numbers.  This gets into cardinal number theory... Adding one to $\aleph_0$ is a lot like adding $-1$ to the set of natural numbers.  There's still the same size infinity of numbers there...

Comment: thank you for the insight! I will try to read up on these topics.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to think of it without limits.

$S \;\,= 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}\ldots$

$2S = 2+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\ldots$

Subtract and all of the terms cancel except for the first one in $2S$ because there are an infinite amount of terms.

$2S-S=2$

$S=2$

The exact value of the infinite sum is 2.

Comment: Though this method is valid for this sum, one must be careful with manipulations like this, lest you find nonsense results like $\sum (-1)^n=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: **Note:** Such algebraic manipulations are only valid for *convergent* series; when applied to non-convergent series you may obtain paradoxical results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an infinite series is defined as a limit.   It either is a value, or does not exist.

In this case (presuming you meant *this* series), the sequence converges so the series exists and its value is exactly $2$.

$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^k} ~=~ & \lim_{n\to\infty} ~\sum_{k=0}^n \frac 1 {2^k} & = 1+\tfrac 12 +\tfrac 14 +\cdots \\[2ex] ~=~& \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2-2^{-n}}{2-1} \\[2ex]~=~& 2\end{align}$$

It is not the case that "... but the series never gets to $2$" or anything like that.    The infinite series is not "going" anywhere.   It is a limit of a sequence of finite series, and that limit *is* a constant: $2$.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you seem to be writing the harmonic series,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k$$
which diverges.
The sum of a series is defined as the limit of the sequence of partial sums, so the geometric series would be
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^Nr^k$$
The partial sum are usually derived by defining
$$S_N=\sum_{k=0}^Nr^k$$
So that $$\begin{align}(r-1)S_N&=\sum_{k=0}^Nr^{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^Nr^k=\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}r^k-\sum_{k=0}^Nr^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^Nr^k+r^{N+1}-\sum_{k=1}^Nr^k-1=r^{N+1}-1\end{align}$$
So
$$S_N=\sum_{k=0}^Nr^k=\frac{r^{N+1}-1}{r-1}$$
Now, if $|r|<1$ this limit
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^Nr^k=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{r^{N+1}-1}{r-1}=\frac1{1-r}$$
Exists, so that is the value of the geometric series exactly. If $|r|\ge1$, of course the limit does not exist so the geometric series doesn't have a real value.